# How is libdl linked on creation of a QObject? Linking from code?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, linker

I've recently encountered a very interesting and confusing behavior when cross-compiling for aarch64 using GCC7 and Qt. Here is a short snippet demonstrating the problem.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  RemoteControl::Internet inet;
  Renderer rend;
  app.exec();
}
```

When I omit the creation of the object that inherits from QObject (the main function looks like this):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  //RemoteControl::Internet inet;
  Renderer rend;
  app.exec();
}
```

I get the following linker error: undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.17'.

My issue is easily solvable by explicitly linking to libdl in CMakeLists file and is probably specific to my platform, but I am pretty puzzled by how creating that one QObject links libdl. I've found out that it is possible to link libraries from code in MSVC using pragma comment, but haven't been able to find an explanation for GCC, so I have come here to ask for one. Any suggestions and possible explanations are welcome.

EDIT:
To add more detail, I edited the code snippet and added a bit of CMake:

```
QT5_WRAP_CPP(Internet_HEADERS_MOC
  include/RemoteControl/Internet.h)

add_library(our_lib STATIC
  src/RemoteControl/Internet.cpp
  src/Renderer.cpp
  ${Internet_HEADERS_MOC}
)

target_link_libraries(our_lib our_other_lib)

add_executable(our_exec src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(our_exec our_lib)
```

When I create an instance of RemoteControl::Internet (which is the aforementioned class which inherits from QOBject) in the main function, linking succeeds, but if I don't and only create an instance of Renderer, linking fails. If more information is needed, feel free to ask, I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Most likely the library containing `createObjInheritingFromQObject` also depends on libdl, that's why your build system automagically adds libdl to the list of libraries.

Comment: See edit, please.